# how to solve sth wrong in conda install openmm

Tags: conda

conda install -c conda-forge openmm cudatoolkit

Downloading and Extracting Packages:

('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(163854709 bytes read, 290245927 more expected)', IncompleteRead(163854709 bytes read, 290245927 more expected))
('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(163854709 bytes read, 290245927 more expected)', IncompleteRead(163854709 bytes read, 290245927 more expected))

how to solve this errors？？？

Downloading and Extracting Packages:

('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(163854709 bytes read, 290245927 more expected)', IncompleteRead(163854709 bytes read, 290245927 more expected))
('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(163854709 bytes read, 290245927 more expected)', IncompleteRead(163854709 bytes read, 290245927 more expected))

how to solve this errors？？？